# Android Volley Crashing

Tags: java, android, nullpointerexception, android-volley

I'm using Android Volley to login a user in but when addToRequestQueue is called the following crash report is shown.

[image: Crash Report]

The login request is carried out onclick in the Loginactivity as follows:

```
// Login button Click Event
    btnLogin.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View view) {
            String username = inputUserName.getText().toString();
            String pin = inputPIN.getText().toString();

            // Check for empty data in the form
            if (username.trim().length() > 0 && pin.trim().length() > 0) {
                // login user

                SharedPreferences prefs = getGCMPreferences(context);
                String storeRegId = prefs.getString(PROPERTY_REG_ID, "");
                String devid = Secure.getString(getBaseContext().getContentResolver(),Secure.ANDROID_ID); 
                String vars = "/?tag=login&username=" + username + "&pin=" + pin + "&regid=" + storeRegId + "&devid=" + devid;

                WebRequest wr = new WebRequest(context);
                wr.Request(AppConfig.URL_LOGIN, vars, true, "Please Wait", "Logging in...", "req_login");


            } else {
                // Prompt user to enter credentials
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Please enter the credentials!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }

    });
```

WebRequest, which uses volley looks like this:

```
package app;

import helper.SQLiteHandler;
import helper.SessionManager;
import helper.dbTables;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicInteger;

import main.MainActivity;

import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.WindowManager;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.android.volley.Response; 
import com.android.volley.VolleyError;
import com.android.volley.Request.Method;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.StringRequest;
import com.google.android.gms.gcm.GoogleCloudMessaging;

public class WebRequest extends Activity {

private static final String TAG = "LoginActivity";

AtomicInteger msgId = new AtomicInteger();
GoogleCloudMessaging gcm;
SharedPreferences prefs;
public SQLiteHandler db;
SessionManager session;

protected Context context;

public WebRequest(Context context){
    this.context = context.getApplicationContext();
} 



public void Request(final String url, final String vars, final Boolean show, final String title, final String msg, final String requestName){


    final SessionManager session = new SessionManager(context);
    final ProgressDialog theProgressDialog = new ProgressDialog(context);
    db = new SQLiteHandler(context);

    if(show == true){
        theProgressDialog.getWindow().setType(WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_SYSTEM_ALERT);
        theProgressDialog.setTitle(title);
        theProgressDialog.setMessage(msg);
        theProgressDialog.setIndeterminate(true);
        theProgressDialog.setCancelable(false);
        theProgressDialog.show();
    }

    StringRequest strreq = new StringRequest(Method.GET, url + vars, 
            new Response.Listener<String>() {

                @Override
                public void onResponse(String response) {
                    Log.d(TAG, "WEB Response: " + response.toString());


                    try {
                        JSONObject jObj = new JSONObject(response);
                        boolean error = jObj.getBoolean("error");

                        // Check for error node in json
                        if (!error) {

                            switch(requestName){
                                case "req_login":
                                    //process user login
                                    // Fetching user details from sqlite

                                    HashMap<String, String> user = db.fetchResults(dbTables.TABLE_LOGIN, null);

                                    String storedUid = user.get("uid");

                                    JSONObject login = jObj.getJSONObject("login"); 


                                    if(storedUid != login.getString("uid")){
                                        //new user for device

                                        String[] emptyTables = {dbTables.TABLE_LOGIN};

                                            for(int i=0; i<emptyTables.length; i++){
                                             db.emptyTable(emptyTables[i]);
                                             Log.d(TAG, "empty table : " + emptyTables[i]);
                                           }

                                    }

                                    //store user in database
                                    db.addUser(login.getString("uid"), 
                                               login.getString("companyid"), 
                                               login.getString("resourceid"), 
                                               login.getString("groupid"), 
                                               login.getString("title"), 
                                               login.getString("firstname"), 
                                               login.getString("middleinitial"), 
                                               login.getString("lastname"), 
                                               login.getString("jobtitle"), 
                                               login.getString("managerid"), 
                                               login.getString("email"), 
                                               login.getString("photo_url"), 
                                               login.getString("signature_url"), 
                                               login.getString("language"), 
                                               login.getString("skin"), 
                                               login.getString("defaultprojectid"), 
                                               login.getString("cnNotifications"), 
                                               login.getString("crNotifications"), 
                                               login.getString("coNotifications"), 
                                               login.getString("addedby"), 
                                               login.getString("dateadded"), 
                                               login.getString("editedby"), 
                                               login.getString("dateedited"));









                                    // Create login session
                                    session.setLogin(true);

                                    // Launch main activity
                                    Intent intent = new Intent(context, MainActivity.class);
                                    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                                    context.startActivity(intent);
                                    //finish();
                                break;
                            }

                            if(show == true){
                                theProgressDialog.dismiss();
                            }
                        }else{
                            String errorMsg = jObj.getString("error_msg");
                            Toast.makeText(context, errorMsg, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                            if(show == true){
                                theProgressDialog.dismiss();
                            }
                        }
                    }catch(JSONException e){
                        // JSON error
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }, new Response.ErrorListener() {

                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                    Log.e(TAG, "Web Error: " + error.getMessage());

                    Toast.makeText(context, error.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                    if(show == true){
                        theProgressDialog.dismiss();
                    }

                }
            });



    // Adding request to request queue
    AppController.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(strreq, requestName);


}

}
```

I've also included the AppController which I haven't personally changed

```
package app;

import android.app.Application;
import android.text.TextUtils;

import com.android.volley.Request;
import com.android.volley.RequestQueue;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.Volley;

public class AppController extends Application {

public static final String TAG = AppController.class.getSimpleName();

private RequestQueue mRequestQueue;

private static AppController mInstance;

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    mInstance = this;
}

public static synchronized AppController getInstance() {
    return mInstance;
}

public RequestQueue getRequestQueue() {
    if (mRequestQueue == null) {
        mRequestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(getApplicationContext());
    }

    return mRequestQueue;
}

public <T> void addToRequestQueue(Request<T> req, String tag) {
    req.setTag(TextUtils.isEmpty(tag) ? TAG : tag);
    getRequestQueue().add(req);
}

public <T> void addToRequestQueue(Request<T> req) {
    req.setTag(TAG);
    getRequestQueue().add(req);
}

public void cancelPendingRequests(Object tag) {
    if (mRequestQueue != null) {
        mRequestQueue.cancelAll(tag);
    }
}
}
```

Comment: that's how ends using stupid androidhive tutorials ... there is no need to use AppController  that extends Application  ... but when you are doing this ... it is good to read the tutorial to the end (you have to do something to force using this class instead normal Application class) ...

Comment: why are you extending the activity ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- This is no way to create a Activity object. A lot get go wrong
  like this.

  - Activity is a context therefore he doesnt need to hold a context
    as a member. That is a common memory leak.
  - The activity doesnt go trough the proper life cycle and that is why
    everything blows up.

I would suggest to you to start from the basic because when you will do this everything will be clearer.

Answer (score 0):

The AppController isn't neccessary in creating a request using volley......Just add the request in volley android volley request.....https://www.simplifiedcoding.net/android-volley-post-request-tutorial/.......

Answer (score 0):

The way you sends the request will determine if the app crashes.....one, the Sqlite will make the application crashes if the request is sent properly...